# Json.NET doesn't decode escaped quotes after deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

Source JSON:

```
[
    {
        "$type": "Test.Contracts.TestClass, Test.Contracts",
        "name": "name1",
        "comments": [
            {
                "title": "Some value",
                "text": "Some value \"in quotes\""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Deserialized string still contains escaped quotes:
[image]

Deserialization code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestClass>>(json,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        });
```

Is there any solution to the problem other than manually replacing `\"` symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio is escaping the quotes for the debugging view, they do not exist in the underlying string.

The easiest solution if you need to see the unquoted version is to press the magnifying glass.